# PhpStrom не подгружает настройки прикрепленного проекта

Tags: phpstorm

Есть два сервиса (назовем их X и Y) в разных репозиториях. У них разные версии php, которые прописаны в composer.json. Когда я к открытому проекту X прикрепляю (attach) другой проект Y, то при попытке редактирования файлов проекта Y, PhpStorm продолжает использовать настройки проекта X. Например: ругается на новые возможности языка; работает с namespace как это указано в composer.json проекта X; не видит настройки фиксера, стана, псалма, и все остальное.

Есть ли способ для каждого attach проекта заставить ide использовать свои настройки ну или хотя бы чтоб подгружался соответствующий composer.json?